# Why does my furnace blower turn on when the thermostat is turned off?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, air-conditioning, heater, blower

The weather has been nice so we have had our thermostat turned off for about a month. The other night it turned on randomly and started blowing warmer to hot air getting the temperature to 78 degrees Fahrenheit. I turned the ac on but it kept blowing warm air so I pulled the thermostat off the wall and the blower turned off. We changed the batteries and put it back on the following day and turned the ac on and it worked cooling the house down. About 24 hours later it later randomly turned on blowing hot air again but the thermostat was off. We took it off the wall again and put it back on but it kept blowing hot air. Today I tried diagnosing the problem but after putting it back on and turning the ac on it worked perfectly fine. Has anyone ever heard or seen something similar?

Comment: What kind of thermostat? Is it just the blower/fan running, or is the heater running too? Do you have a boiler or electric/gas forced air heater? Does the blower run when the thermostat is disconnected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome Preston!  You mentioned "getting the temp to 78F" - what was the temp before?  Also, is your split system in the attic, such that residual heat from the sun might have warmed the ducts and system, so if the fan kicked on, it might warm the home without the heat being on?  Also, some modern thermostats might kick the fan on to circulate air with the right setting enabled (usually says "CIRC" on the thermostat).

Comment: Brand/model of the thermostat? What does "pull it off the wall" mean? What did you do to try to diagnose the problem - telling us that will save a lot of time telling you to do things you've already done...

Comment: Fredric- the thermostat and blower are both carrier and is electric. The heater is running too but it turns on randomly when it is set to off. When I pull the thermostat off the wall the blower shuts off after a minute or two.

Comment: Gnicko- I'm asking why my heater turns on when it is set to off. It has never done this before.

Comment: Pbarranis- the temp before was 71 degrees and went to 78 in about 5 to 10 minutes. My duct is in the attic but the outside temp is about 70 so I wouldn't think my attic would make it that hot? My thermostat does not say anything similar to that.

Comment: Freeman- I just take the thermostat off the wall to where you can see the wires. I changed the batteries in the thermostat and changed the filter in case that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an intermittent short-circuit affecting the "call-for-heat" wires, or a problem on a circuit board with the same effect as that.

Intermittent faults are generally annoying to find, but start with **carefully** examining the wiring at both ends, looking for insulation damage or excess bare wire. If you are "throughly out of heating season" you could disconnect the appropriate wire at the furnace end, which would tell you if it was a "circuitboard in the furnace" problem if it recurred, or wiring/thermostat if it does not recur that way.

If it does not recur, and you don't find anything, you could also disconnect the appropriate wire at the thermostat (reconnecting it at the furnace) to see if it happens with just the wires connected, indicating a likely "damage in wall" (think mice, unless there's been construction activity) to the wire.

If both of those behave, that makes the thermostat suspect. Pretty much need to replace it with a different one at that point.

Comment: It might also be a recalcitrant timer controlling the furnace fan and fresh air intake duct.   Most ducted systems have that to bring some fresh air into modern, tightly sealed houses. ...just a thought.

Comment: Question states "warmer-to-hot air" which seems to indicate heat coming on, since it was "nice" and neither heat nor the AC was on as I read the question, so wouldn't seem like outside would be hot at that point.

Comment: Maybe, but ductwork in non-insulated spaces can still get quite hot even in mild weather.   If the fresh air intake was operating randomly, it could pull heated air into the house.   But it could be several other causes as well.   NOTE:  BTW is it just me or is the @ (commenter) not working anymore? It used to bring up the screen name of the person making the comment, but doesn't anymore, at least for me.

Comment: thanks Ecnerwal for responding, still not working, I'll try in another browser (currently I use Firefox).

Comment: Just an update to the post, it came back on when it was set to off. I changed it to cool and the line outside all the way to the blower were both cold and sweating but it was still blowing warm air making it climb up to 76 before I shut it off. I'm going to try what ecnerwal suggested and see if that works. Sorry for the late responses, I thought I would get an email of all comments but I haven't received anything .

Comment: I disconnected the wire at the furnace end and that shut the heater off but now the ac does not work properly. It blows about room temperature, i traced it back and everything gets cold all the way to the coils then the top half of the coils are quite a bit warmer than the bottom half. I dont have a way of measuring the temperature but I would say a good 15 degrees warmer than the bottom. Did I disconnect the wrong wire and mess something up?